# Global value for localStorage as oppossed to per domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

What happens when we use localStorage in a Chrome extension ?

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

`foo` is stored in its respective localStorage for every website we visit ?

So 10 different website visits mean 10 versions of `foo` ?

Is there a way to store `foo` globally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use chrome.storage.local, you can store data "globally" for the entire extension. But only the extension will have access to it, websites will not.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: This is superb news. Does `chrome.storage` work in Edge ? I'm building the same code for publishing to their respective stores. Wondering if I have to create separate packages for each.

Comment: chrome.storage works in Edge, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage#browser_compatibility